# glm() splitting first variable in different ones for each value?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm

I'm trying to do a logistic regression between two variables, where I want to extract the p-value of the correlation between them. However, it seems that the function glm() splits the dependable variable into the unique values it contains, and I receive only a p-value for each of them and not one for the entire variable. Is there a way to instead get a p-value for the entire dependent variable? That's what I get if I do the test in SPSS, so it seems it's possible with logistic regression in general. But is it in R with this function?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
attach(PlantGrowth)
weight.factor<- cut(weight, 2, labels=c('Light', 'Heavy')) # binarize weights
plot(table(group, weight.factor))
group
glm.1<- glm(weight.factor~group, family=binomial)
summary(glm.1)
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the `data` argument to `glm` instead of `attach`: `help("attach")` itself says that you should *usually not use `attach()` ...

```r
pg <- transform(PlantGrowth,
   weight.factor = cut(weight, 2, labels=c('Light', 'Heavy')))
glm.1 <- glm(weight.factor~group, family=binomial, data = pg)
```

`anova()` will test each term in the model:

```r
anova(glm.1, test="Chisq")
...
Terms added sequentially (first to last)
      Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)   
NULL                     29     41.054            
group  2   11.084        27     29.970 0.003919 **
```

or `car::Anova()`

```r
car::Anova(glm.1)
Analysis of Deviance Table (Type II tests)

Response: weight.factor
      LR Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)   
group   11.084  2   0.003919 **
```

You have to be careful/think about the testing sequence when your models are more complicated (contain more than one term, and especially when they contain interaction terms). The defaults for `car::Anova()` come closer to what most people want, but if you have interactions in the model you should still read the "Details" section of `help("Anova", package="car")`

Comment: Thanks you @ben-bolker. Using anova(x, test="Chisq") worked perfectly, and extracting the p-value with `$"Pr(>Chi"[2]`.
Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this?

```
1-pchisq(glm.1$null.deviance-glm.1$deviance, df = glm.1$df.null - glm.1$df.residual)
```

Output:

```
0.003918751
```

Comment: this happens to give the correct example in this case, but doesn't work more generally (if there are more terms in the model), and is hard to understand for anyone who doesn't already know what it's doing (I would write it at as `with(glm.1, pchisq(null.deviance - deviance, df = df.null - df.residual, lower.tail = FALSE))`)